# Accessing hashes in Perl templates

Tags: html, perl, templates, hash, cgi

How do you access variables in a hash when using Perl's [`HTML::Template`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTemplate) module?

I'm building the following hash in my Perl code:

```
# Load success/error flash messages
if ($query->param("submit")) {
  $template->param(
    FLASH => {
      CLASS => "success",
      MESSAGE => "Your cart has been successfully updated!"
    }
  );
}
```

I'd like to access these variables in my template. To access a regular variable, you do:

```
<TMPL_VAR NAME=FLASH>
```

How might I access FLASH['CLASS'] in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the documentation that indicates you can set a parameter as a hashref. The closest to what you want to do is to put the hashref in an arrayref:

```
$template->param(
    FLASH => [ {
        CLASS => "success",
        MESSAGE => "Your cart has been successfully updated!"
    } ]
);
```

Then you can access it as:

```
<TMPL_LOOP NAME=FLASH>
  <TMPL_VAR NAME=CLASS>
  <TMPL_VAR NAME=MESSAGE>
</TMPL_LOOP>
```

But having an array with a single element might be overkill. An alternative is to get rid of the hashref and flatten the structure:

```
$template->param(
    FLASH.CLASS   => "success",
    FLASH.MESSAGE => "Your cart has been successfully updated!"
);

...

<TMPL_VAR NAME=FLASH.CLASS>
<TMPL_VAR NAME=FLASH.MESSAGE>
```

Comment: this is described at the end of [the section on TMPL_LOOP](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Template#TMPL_LOOP) in the documentation.

Comment: I read through the documentation and couldn't find it, but I thought there might be a trick I was missing. Thanks for your explanation. I'll flatten the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Access with a . (dot)

FLASH.CLASS

Answer (score 1):

HTML::Template always needs a hash of arrays of hash of arrays and so on.
If you have an arbitrary data structure you might want to try HTML::Template::Compiled where you can use the dot syntax (disclaimer: I'm the author)

There is also HTML::Template::Plugin::Dot but I have never tested it and it seems to be a bit more limited.